# Start SignalR connection after calling stop

Tags: javascript, signalr

I have two methods in my SignalRService class on client side:

```
public startConnection(): void {  

    this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {  
        console.log('Now connected ' + data.transport.name + ', connection 
ID= ' + data.id);  
        //this.connectionEstablished.emit(true);  
        this.connectionExists = true;  
    }).fail((error: any) => {  
        console.log('Could not connect ' + error);  
        //this.connectionEstablished.emit(false);  
    });  
    }  

    public stopConnection():void {
        this.connection.stop();
            console.log('Stop connection');  
    }
```

Initialization goes in constructor like this:

```
 this.connection = $.hubConnection(environment.apiUrl);  
    this.connection.qs = "Bearer="+this._authService.getToken();
    // create new proxy as name already given in top  
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy(this.proxyName);
```

I need to call start again after stop but it fails with exception:

```
ERROR Error: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use 
.start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection has 
started.
```

Help me please with it!